# Combobox suggestions

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I tried with the `for each` loop to populate the text box with studentid, when I choose the name from the combo-box. The problem is when I choose a name from the combo-box; it is not choosing the corresponding ID, and the ID is not changing.  Do I have to use data tables?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace DBExample
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private OleDbConnection dbConn; // Connectionn object
        private OleDbCommand dbCmd;     // Command object
        private OleDbDataReader dbReader;// Data Reader object
        private Member aMember;
        private string sConnection;
        // private TextBox tb1;
        // private TextBox tb2;

        private string sql;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // Construct an object of the OleDbConnection 
                // class to store the connection string 
                // representing the type of data provider 
                // (database) and the source (actual db)
                sConnection =
                "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
                "Data Source=c:member.mdb";
                dbConn = new OleDbConnection(sConnection);
                dbConn.Open();

                // Construct an object of the OleDbCommand 
                // class to hold the SQL query. Tie the  
                // OleDbCommand object to the OleDbConnection
                // object
                sql = "Select * From memberTable Order " +
                      "By LastName , FirstName ";
                dbCmd = new OleDbCommand();
                dbCmd.CommandText = sql;
                dbCmd.Connection = dbConn;

                // Create a dbReader object 
                dbReader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (dbReader.Read())
                {
                    aMember = new Member
                            (dbReader["FirstName"].ToString(),
                             dbReader["LastName"].ToString(),
                             dbReader["StudentId"].ToString(),
                             dbReader["PhoneNumber"].ToString());

                    // tb1.Text = dbReader["FirstName"].ToString();
                    // tb2.Text = dbReader["LastName"].ToString();

                    // tb1.Text = aMember.X().ToString();

                    //tb2.Text = aMember.Y(aMember.ID).ToString();  

                    this.comboBox1.Items.Add(aMember.FirstName.ToString());                   

                    // this.listBox1.Items.Add(aMember.ToString());
                    // MessageBox.Show(aMember.ToString());
                    // Console.WriteLine(aMember.ToString());
                }
                dbReader.Close();
                dbConn.Close();
            }
            catch (System.Exception exc)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("show" + exc);
            }
        }

        private void DbGUI_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

            //textBox2.Text = string.Empty;
            foreach (var Item in comboBox1.Items);
                textBox2.Text += aMember.ID.ToString();

            //MessageBox.Show("read one record");
        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

The class file is as follows

```
using System;
namespace DBExample
{
    public class Member
    {
        private string id;
        private string firstName;
        private string lastName;
        private string phoneNumber;

        public Member()
            : this("Not", "Assigned", "No ID", "No Phone Service")
        {
        }

        // Constructor
        public Member(string firstname, string lastname, string studentid, string phonenumber)
        {
            this.firstName = firstname;
            this.lastName = lastname;
            this.id = studentid;
            this.phoneNumber = phonenumber;
        }

        public string FirstName
        {
            get
            {
                return firstName;
            }
        }

        public string LastName
        {
            get
            {
                return lastName;
            }
        }

        public string ID
        {
            get
            {
                return id;
            }
        }

        public string PhoneNumber
        {
            get
            {
                return phoneNumber;
            }
        }

        public double X()
        {

            return -5.7;
        }//X()

        public int Y(string id)
        {
            int g;
            g = Convert.ToInt32(id);
            return g + 100000;
        }//Y()

        public int Z() { int m = 100; return m; }

        public override string ToString()
        {            
            return lastName + "\t" + firstName + "\t" + id + "\t" + phoneNumber + "\t" + X() + "\t" + Y(id) + "\t Z is " + Z();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please shorten your code to what is relevant to the problem at hand. This piece of code is way longer that what most of us (including me) are ready to read. For example, your Member class can most likely be limited to the definition of fields (or auto-properties)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're adding items as strings to combobox instead of adding items itself:

Here:

```
this.comboBox1.Items.Add(aMember.FirstName.ToString());
```

Should be:

```
this.comboBox1.Items.Add(aMember);
```

In designer set `ValueMember` for combobox to be `ID` ([msdn](http://ttp://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember.aspx))

Instead of this (which doesn't make any sense):

```
foreach (var Item in comboBox1.Items);
    textBox2.Text += aMember.ID.ToString();
```

Use this:

```
textBox2.Text += combobox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
```